# CPU Permanent throttles after 5 minutes of gaming, util restart

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, performance, cpu

I'm currently running Ubuntu Budgie, on my Asus Zenbook UX550ve, but i also had this issue on my previous OS, PopOS!.

Basically after 10 minutes of gaming, my computer starts to perform really poor. You would think it was a throttle issue due to heat, but quitting the game doesn't improve performance. (And looking at the temps doesn't seem alarming)

This is cpupower frequency-info before gaming,

```
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.80 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.80 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 2.26 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

And this is after

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.80 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.80 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 266 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Its current frequency will range from 200 to 800. Only a restart brings back normal levels.

I've have tried the following

Updating my bios.

Update to latest graphics driver (1050TI).

Pulling the battery from the motherboard for 2 minutes.

Force performance mode with `sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance`

But neither works. It's incredible frustrating, and i'm all out of ideas. :/

Comment: Could be overheating. Check the temps with the `sensors` command. ...and by the way, "looking at the temps doesn't seem alarming" is as vague as it gets.

Comment: @mikewhatever Currently running with 298 MHz, temps are around 50c. I don't think it's due to overheating, probably something with pstate

Comment: Reported CPU frequencies below the minimum mean that there is throttling, probably Clock Modulation. The recommended tool for monitoring this stuff (for modern Intel Processors) is `turbostat`, included in the linux-tools-common package. I would run `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,IRQ --interval 15` always in a terminal. Also try without `--quiet` to see a big spew of stuff that should reveal if a thermal trigger has fired.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer may have some minimal tools in BIOS to prevent overheat damage - and the processor being hot may not translate to "my computer feels hot to the touch"

I use a set of utilities to manage power and thermal (potential) problem in my laptop.  First, install power management tools, and a program to limit CPU speed in severe cases

```
sudo apt install tlp thermald
```

Tlp has many customizable settings in `/etc/default/tlp`

Secondly, install programs to show me the internal temperatures of my computer:

```
sudo apt install --install-suggests lm-sensors psensor
sudo sensors-detect
```

just follow the prompts. Add the recommended lines to /etc/modules.

Now, if you don't want to reboot, you'll have to manually activate the modules.

```
sudo modprobe module1 module2
```

where module1 etc. = the module names provided from sensors-detect.

You may also need to add utilities to control the fan in your laptop

```
sudo apt install fancontrol
sudo pwmconfig
```

and work your way through the instructions there.

Finally, run sensors -s to make your fan configuration take effect.

```
sudo sensors -s
```

Now, you can check your temps.

```
sensors
```

Now to run fan control, type:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/fancontrol &
```